# PHP probleme while remove columns in csv

Tags: php, csv, multiple-columns

I use the php script below to remove some columns from a csv, order them new and save it as new file.
And it works for the file i made it for.
Now i need to do the same with another csv but i don't know whats wrong. I always get a comma befor the data in the first column.

This is what i have, but it doesn't really work.

```
<?php
$input = 'http://***/original.csv';
$output = 'new.csv';

if (false !== ($ih = fopen($input, 'r'))) {
$oh = fopen($output, 'w');

while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) {
    // this is where you build your new row
    $outputData = array($data[4], $data[0]);
    fputcsv($oh, $outputData);
}

fclose($ih);
fclose($oh);
}
```

The original.csv looks that:

```
subproduct_number   barcode        stock    week_number qty_estimate    productid   variantid
05096470000         4024144513543   J                   3               6           35016
ae214               848518017215    N       23          0               7           35015
05097280000         4024144513727   J                   1               32          34990
```

The seperator is ';'. The same seperator is used in the file that is working

But here it will be go wrong because my saved new.csv looks like this:

```
subproduct_number   barcode        stock    week_number qty_estimate    productid   variantid
,05096470000        4024144513543   J                   3               6           35016
,ae214              848518017215    N       23          0               7           35015
,05097280000        4024144513727   J                   1               32          34990
```

But what i need is a new csv that looks like this:

```
  qty_estimate  subproduct_number
  3             05096470000
  0             ae214
  1             05097280000
```

As you can see, i need only the 5. column ($data[4]) as first and the first column ($data[0]) as the second one.

I hope someone can point me in the reight direction. 
Thanks

Comment: Add `echo "<pre/>";print_r($data);die;` inside `while()` and see what output came. show us that output.

Comment: If the column separator is not a comma you have to specify it at when calling `fgetcsv`, Look at the [php doc of fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) there is a `$delemiter` char.

Comment: I added the echo as suggested from Alive to Die--Anant singh and got this:
    `code  Array
    (
    [0] => subproduct_number;barcode;stock;week_number;qty_estimate;productid;variantid;
    )`
(without the first 'code')

Comment: @ Alive to Die...
I did as you suggested below, but now i get only a single column with "qty_estimate,subproduct_number" in the first row. But the column is also empty

Answer (score 1):

You can do so:

```
while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) {
    $data = explode(';', $data[0]);
    $outputData = array($data[4], $data[0]);
    fputcsv($oh, $outputData, ';');
}
```